# When I fetch all the data in Object in Django, get the error like ''str' object has no attribute 'values'"

Tags: python, django

I want to get the all the values inside the object, `obj.values()` method and I got the error like ''str' object has no attribute 'values'"

```
**Views.py**


def upload_list(request):
    pdf = Client_files.objects.all()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        obj = request.POST.get('btSelectItem')
        print(obj.values())
    return render(request, 'uploadpdf.html', {'pdf' : pdf,})
```

Comment: I think you've mixed up your `pdf` and `obj` variables. `pdf` is the QuerySet you can call `values()` on; `obj` is a string from the POSTed data.

Comment: No, I don't mix the pdf and obj

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `obj` only return the string after passing to the `Client_Files` model and get the object and then got the values in `obj.values()` method

```
def upload_list(request):
    pdf = Client_files.objects.all()

    if request.method == 'POST':
        obj = request.POST.get('btSelectItem')
        print(obj)
        obj2 = Client_files.objects.filter(id=obj)
        obj3 = obj2.values_list('client')
    return render(request, 'uploadpdf.html', {'pdf' : pdf,})
```